# What is the turnaround time for the following scheduling algorithm?

Tags: multithreading, process

I was just given this example in class and it seemed as if my professor was not too sure about his answer on it. I have come here for a more detailed explanation.

Given 5 batch jobs, A through E, all arrive at a computer center at the same time.

For the following scheduling algorithm, determine the mean process turnaround time. Ignore process switching overhead. Assume that the system is multi programmed and each jobs gets it’s fair share of cpu.

- Round Robin

Process:         Run time(min):
A                 10
B                 6
C                 2
D                 4
E                 8

My professors answer: 33 min turnaround time

Comment: Why do you think your professor was "not too sure?" Did you ask the prof to explain their answer? Seems as if the puzzle is to figure out how long each job takes. All start at the same time, all receive 1/5 of the CPU. After some number of minutes, the shortest job (C) will finish. Then, until the next finishes, others will each receive 1/4 of the CPU, etc. The numbers you were given (A 10, B 6, ...) _probably\*_ are the number of minutes each job would take if it had the _full_ CPU. The answer _probably_ should be the average (a.k.a., "arithmetic _mean_") of how long each job actually took.

Comment: \* Only your prof knows for sure what those numbers _actually_ mean.

Comment: The letters are the individual jobs and the numbers that follow are how long the runtime is for the jobs(in minutes). I only suspected he was a little unsure because my professor did a couple of "double-takes" with his final answer and changing it a couple of times. So, I asked this question just to get another understanding of it from somewhere else.

Comment: Re, "runtime for the job(in minutes)," Yes, but do those numbers represent real time (a.k.a., "wall-clock time") or do they represent CPU time? I'm _guessing_ that the given numbers represent CPU time, and that the answer is supposed to represent real-time. Otherwise, I don't see how the question makes any sense. My first comment, above, explains how I personally "solved" the problem that I _think_ you are being asked (i.e., based on those two guesses.) It felt right. But I'm not going to do your homework for you. You should to talk to the prof or to a TA or to a classmate who seems to know...